# What is required to get OGR to work with SQL Server?

Tags: qgis, gdal, ogr, sql-server, sql-server-spatial

All,

I've been having heaps of trouble getting OGR to connect to our SQL Server development environment. (read about it [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66532/why-does-importing-data-through-mssql-provider-throw-this-error) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66712/why-does-ogr2ogr-shp-import-error-out-trying-to-create-a-database))

**SQL Versions**: 2008, 2012
**OS's**: Windows 7, Ubuntu 12.04

My questions are:

1) What permissions does the user need in order to establish a connection to a SQL Server database with OGR?

2) Does anything need to be loaded on the SQL Server machine or application server itself?

I used to be able to connect even with QGIS, [but that isn't working now either](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67983/what-does-ogr-driver-not-loaded-mean-when-connecting-to-sql-server-through-qgi). ([or here either](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66340/why-cant-qgis-connect-to-ms-sql-server-edited))

Also: if you have a password with a ! in it, it will throw back a 'bash' error...fyi!

Ok thanks again, all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can write to SQL Server 2008 with GDAL 1.10.1 using below command. I'm using SQL Server auth entication and a user that has connect, create procedure, create table, create view, select and showplan. I suspect that I only need, connect and create table for below.

Although I have also had to delete the geometry columns and spatial ref system tables at times 'manually'. At the moment these do not exist but this command works.

```
U:\>ogr2ogr -overwrite -nln "LCCGIS.CAD_Parcels_JSON" -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=SQL2008P1\MSSQLSERVER32BIT;database=GISTEST;Uid=lccgis;pwd=password" jsonURL -lco "DIM=2"
```

Comment: I get the errors described here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164680/what-if-geometry-columns-already-exists-in-mssql-server-database