# What if 'geometry_columns' already exists in MSSQL Server Database?

Tags: gdal, sql-server, ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

When trying to load a .SHP into MSSQLSpatial using OGR2OGR, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1: Error initializing the metadata tables : [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Dr
iver][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'geometry_columns' in the data
base.
```

I can see the entries using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM giswork.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where table_name like 'geometry%'
```

And the result looks like this:

[image]

And If I dig deeper with this query:

```
select * from matthew_baker.geometry_columns
```

I get a set of empty results:

[image]

**My questions**:

- What should be in the geometry_columns table (if it's not there already...)
- Why does og2ogr throw the error about the geometry_columns table already being created?

**EDIT**: It seems that GDAL ***created*** these tables when I tried to use the OGR2OGR command - they have not been in my database until now. My current spatial data was created using FME and is updated with FME.

I can view AND edit my MSSQLSpatial tables in QGIS 2.10 without any issues, across multiple schemas in my database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have stumbled on this issue lately, and if you set the MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS environment variable to NO, then the error message disappears. Related documentation [here](http://gdal.org/1.11/ogr/drv_mssqlspatial.html).

Hope it helps somebody later.

Comment: Thanks - do you put that in the connection string or outside? Still getting the error in both cases unfortunately...

Comment: Add it as an environment variable, not as part of the connection string.  On Windows e.g. https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500

Comment: Does that have to occur on the machine the server resides on? or the Client machine?

Comment: It has to be on the machine where you run the command.

Comment: Aargh still not working - set the environment variable as both a user and system variable... even restarted... still getting the error... Maybe I'll test to see if it needs to be set on the server...

Comment: Just FYI, I use og2ogr version 2.0.2, don't know if that matters... but good luck anyways!!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use environment variables (or dont have permissions) adding `--config MSSQLSPATIAL_USE_GEOMETRY_COLUMNS NO` to the command has solved this issue for me.

Comment: Awesome.  Great to have this completely handled on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I have a partial answer to part 2 of your question 'Why does ogr2ogr throw the error about the geometry_columns table already being created?'

I'm performing a .SHP into MSSQLSpatial using OGR2OGR and also getting the

```
ERROR 1: Error initializing the metadata tables : [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Dr
iver][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'geometry_columns' in the data
base.
```

The MSSQL database I'm loading to also has SDE on it.  There is no table called geometry_columns but there is a table called sde_geometry_colums and a stored procedure name geometry_columns.  My guess is that ogr2ogr is checking whether a table called geometry_columns exists and if it doesn't then create it.  So  it's not finding the geometry_columns table and then trying to create the geometry_columns table.  Because there is an object (the stored proc) called geometry_columns an error will be thrown when ogr2ogr tries to create a table of the same name.  I tested this by renaming the stored proc and re-running ogr2ogr and I no longer get the error.  I'm performing all this on a test database and I don't know what the implications are for SDE by renaming this stored proc...

Comment: Thanks for the info... by the way, is there a reason you're loading spatial data into the back-end of an ArcSDE database rather than as an SDE feature class through the 'front end'?

Comment: I've got a separate machine with QGIS and MSSQL spatial, and I'm trying to create a workflow that doesn't involve any ESRI software.  I was having some data loading  issues on this machine and thought I'd try the ogr2ogr on my machine with SDE on it to see if I could resolve the issue there (by exporting the data out of sde and reloading through ogr2ogr as the data had already passed through the load process using ArcGIS front-end), and that's how stumbled on this error.

Comment: Ahhh! Good stuff. We're in the same boat, but use PostGIS as the 'source' of the spatial data, and use python to move the data to mssql sever - otherwise, going straight from QGIS To MSSQL is still not working for us...