# ERROR 1: Error initializing the metadata tables :

Tags: postgis, gdal, sql-server, ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

I use ogr2ogr (bundled with QGIS 2.14.3) on Windows to convert an ArcSDE MS SQL Server 2012 database with SQL Geometry to PostGIS (2.1.8). I use the following syntax:

> ogr2ogr --config PGCLIENTCODING ISO-8859-2 -f "PostgreSQL"
>   PG:"host=localhost user=postgres dbname=atlas password=secret"
>   "MSSQL:server=srv-sql;database=test;trusted_connection=yes"
>   -a_srs "EPSG:23700" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom

It seems to do the conversion, all tables are copied, but I get this error:

> ERROR 1: Error initializing the metadata tables :

From other post it seems that it is related to the MS SQL driver or the geometry_columns table, but I can't seem to find the problem as the error message does not continue...

Do I need to worry about this? Or how to get rid of this?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to your question? Im getting the same error message and it continues with: `[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'SomeDatabaseName'.`

Comment: It's been awhile since I had this question, though I could find what was the problem in my case, see my answer for another question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164680/what-if-geometry-columns-already-exists-in-mssql-server-database/220375#220375